# Chrome Extension: data retrieval from Local storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am trying to build an extension which authenticates to a test server in a popup window, and retrieve the data from test server and stores it into the local storage through background script, and displays the same on popup.html. The problem is, i am able to store the data coming from the server, but am not able to display it in first authentication. I have to login again, and only then i can display the data i retrieved from test server?
Any hint or advised will be much appreciated.

Popup.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from: "login", user: username, pass: password, subject: "page_details"},function(response) 
{   

    //Sends message to background to start content script.
  var login_response = response.type1;

    if(login_response == "DONE")
    {
        //window.location = "index.html";
    }
  if(login_response == "INVALID")
  {

  }
});
```

Backgroundscript.js

```
 if (msg.from && (msg.from === "login")
            && msg.subject && (msg.subject = "page_details"))
      {   
chrome.tabs.executeScript( { file: 'contentscript.js' });
          sendResponse({'type1':"DONE"});
        }
```

Contentscript.js:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    var raw_data = xhr.responseText;
    var project_details = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);


chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from: "content2", subject: "page_details", data: raw_data},function(response) 
    {


    });
```

backgroundscript.js:

```
if (msg.from && (msg.from === "content2")
            && msg.subject && (msg.subject = "page_details"))
      {
        var project_name = [];
        chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
        var raw_details = msg.data;
        var project_details = JSON.parse(msg.data);

        localStorage["Project"] = JSON.stringify(project_name);
}
```

and in index.html (another popup page of an extension) i populate localStorage["Project"], But i couldn't been able to populate project details in one go i have to reload the page and then only i can able to populate it on index.html

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking, or how the question title relates to it.

Comment: Xan, Sorry for my technical fault in the language. I simply want to say that i recieve data from a test server(Using ajax call) and store that into my background script but when i try to display data on popup.html i failed.
For More clearance i can provide you code snippets if you want.

Comment: Yes. Please do provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question to include clarifications instead of dumping them in the comments.

Comment: Good, but also please cleanly explain what the logic behind the code should be, step by step, and what fails. Your descriptive part of the question is still not understandable.

Comment: Also, the key part of how you "populate" `localStorage["Project"]` is missing

Comment: Hey Xan, as you can see i have include localStorage["Project"] part, as you see localStorage["Project"] updates later than index.html that's why i have to login twice in order to populate popup.html with Local["Storage"].